# Why ngrok tries to redirect to https scheme?

Tags: ngrok

I have an http server which runs over `http` scheme only (no SSL). If I access the site locally through http://localhost:80 (note that https://localhost:80 is not supported) everything works fine. I decided to access the site from outside with ngrok using the `http` scheme only. So I started ngrok with the following command:

```
ngrok http 80 --scheme http
```

[image]

Ngrok starts successfully and provide me only with a `http` link that when pasted in the browser redirects to `https` scheme. Since `https` is not enabled ngrok gives me an error `ERR_NGROK_3200`.

So is redirecting to `https` an expected behaviour? How to explicitely force ngrok to stop redirecting to `https`?

```
$ ngrok --version
ngrok version 3.4.0
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

P.S. The following is a part of a CURL GET command:

```
*   Trying 3.125.223.134:80...
* Connected to *****************.ngrok-free.app (*.***.***.134) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: *****************.ngrok-free.app
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2023 15:17:09 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Ngrok-Trace-Id: 854d49a42c0fb1e8f7e4cf84f872af30
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Debian)
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1c8a7c470af71b572c5e437ce391a3a8; path=/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.33
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It looks like ngrok is not the one who makes the redirect, but the browser. I tried Chrome and Firefox and both act the same way -  redirecting to https.

Comment: Have you checked what the server actually returns when you try to access the URL via e.g. curl?

Comment: Hm, CURL get successfully the actual page. It looks like the problem is in the browser. It redirects to HTTPS without receiving a redirect header. I tried with Firefox as well - same error.

Comment: @maio290, please check my the edit with CURL response in the question above!

Comment: Yeah, I think your article might be true. I was expecting to see a 301 here, but it's looking fine. So I guess it's up to the behaviour of the browser, it's really annoying. For Firefox, there might be a flag to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that explains why the browser redirects to https - https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025832811--dev-and-app-domains-force-HTTPS-by-default

Also this - https://ngrok.com/blog-post/new-ngrok-domains

It looks like since the ngrok's domain name ends with .app, the browser always redirects to `https`.

Note: If you forward with ngrok a page in your browser using HTTPS, the browser will refuse to load any resources over HTTP. In the browser's developer console (in my case Google Chrome) you will see an error like this:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://1111-22-33-444-55.ngrok-free.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'https://1111-22-33-444-55.ngrok-free.app//config/js/all.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`
To go around that problem you can tell ngrok to attach to the HTTP response **Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests** header like so:

```
ngrok http 80 --response-header-add='Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests'
```

Answer (score 2):

PM from ngrok here. We are currently working on getting additional domains that do not require https to access. just waiting on this [public suffix PR](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/pull/1895) to merge and them we can turn them on for customers.